# Download .IPA media without physically create a .PLIST file

Tags: ios, asp.net, umbraco

I have been asked to create a "Download our app" button, with an IOS app in mind. I am using the CMS "Umbraco" and the users should only have to upload the ".IPA"-file. The backend should take care of the rest.

How do I do this nicely? I could of cause create a new .slist file everytime someone presses the download button, but that doesn't really make sense to me. Are there someway of creating a ".PLIST" on the fly? Maybe, without even saving it? Sent through headers maybe?

Looking for ideas :)

Comment: Noone with any ideas? :)

Comment: Maybe you can create an UmbracoApiController ( https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/Reference/Routing/WebApi/ ) with your custom logic that returns the content of your plist file and with an url rewrite make it respond on a custom url like /info.plist